# Android recyclerview's item animate

Tags: android

I have a horizontal recyclerview and I'm going to animate the visible and focused item on the screen.

```
  public MyViewholder(final View item) {
        super(itemView);
   //...
   item.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.scale_in);
                    card.startAnimation(anim);
                    anim.setFillAfter(true);
                } else {
                    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.scale);
                    card.startAnimation(anim);
                    anim.setFillAfter(true);
                }
            }
            });
}
```

The problem is only the first item of recyclerview has animate and other items does not change.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    android:id="@+id/card">

 ...

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
  public MyViewholder(final View itemView) {
  super(itemView);
  itemView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.scale_in);
                itemView.startAnimation(anim);
                anim.setFillAfter(true);
            } else {
                Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.scale);
                itemView.startAnimation(anim);
                anim.setFillAfter(true);
            }
        }
        });
  }
```